# How do I use a conditional to filter channel results?

Tags: conditionals

I need to be able to display only a subset of channel entries based on membership expiration date.

I am looking to display only those entries where the Expiration Date is less than or equal to today.

Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="member_profiles" group_id="9|10|11|12|13|14|15"  orderby="business_expire_date" sort="asc"}
 {if {business_expire_date format="%U"} <= {current_time format="%U"} }
    <tr class="{switch='odd|even'}">
        <td><a href="/member-reports/profile/{url_title}">{member_business}</a></td>
        <td>{full_name}</td>
        <td>{business_enroll_date format="%M %d, %Y"}</td>
        <td class="expired"> {business_expire_date format="%M %d, %Y"}</td>
    </tr>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When I load the page I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL in /home/...

How do I modify the {if} statement to correct that?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you wrap your dates in quotes? ie. `{if "{business_expire_date format='%U'}" ...`

Comment: Hi Jason, that helped. I had to get rid of the formatting too and now it works fine. Please elevate your comment to a response and I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your dates in quotes.

```
{if "{business_expire_date}" <= "{current_time}"}
```